# Comparing two columns in pivot table

Tags: looker-studio

How can I compare two columns as a percentage in pivot table?

Data sample is here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CSgHRGXKqFlDnQxb8SuERi_GLZ5waeXF/view?usp=sharing

| latitude | longitude | email | hour | year | avg_number_of_vehicles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41.20697021 | 28.58093262 | O-7, İstanbul, Türkiye | 1 | 2021 | 28.51260504 |
| 41.20697021 | 28.58093262 | O-7, İstanbul, Türkiye | 2 | 2020 | 26.47787611 |
| 41.20697021 | 28.58093262 | O-7, İstanbul, Türkiye | 3 | 2021 | 19.6969697 |

Current Pivot table:

1. Row dimension: hour
2. Column dimension: year
3. Metric:avg_number_of_vehicles

I want to add another column shows difference of year(2020 and 2021)

Here is current setup: https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/6311253e-be40-4275-9b3c-1ab6188d0f7d
[image]